# Prove $m(G \sim E)=0 \leftrightarrow$ the union of two measurable sets is measurable.

Tags: analysis

I'm driving myself nuts with this, can anybody please help? I'm going in circles on paper. I have my work here. I think my proof to the previous problem is ok, but can't take off on this. It's problem 21 at the bottom of the document. Please help, will accept advice.

https://www.overleaf.com/read/gwvqbbfqbctk

Use property (ii) of Theorem 11 as the primitive definition of a measurable set and prove that the union of two measurable sets is measurable.

Theorem 11 says:
Let $E $ be any set of real numbers. Then the following is equivalent to the measurability of $E$:

$(ii)$ There is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ containing $E$ for which $m^*(G\sim E)=0$.

Note:
$m^*(G\sim E)$ is the outer (or "Lebesgue") measure of the set in G without E

$G_\delta$, as I understand it, is the intersection of *countable* open sets, which is not necessarily open.

Comment: The only reason I posted a link is because I had no access to a computer and had to use my phone. It is a LaTex document.

Comment: A $G_\delta$ set is the intersection of a ***COUNTABLE*** collection of open sets. (Without the "countable" restriction it's meaningless; every set of real numbers is the intersection of some collection of open sets.) From the context, I'm guessing that $\sim$ is the notation your book uses for the symmetric difference of two sets? Since $G$ contains $E$ you could say more simply that $m^*(G\setminus E)=0.$

Comment: You need to show two things (or maybe they have already been established in your class): That $$(G_1\cup G_2)\sim(E_1\cup E_2)\subseteq(G_1\sim E_1)\cup(G_2\sim E_2)$$ and that the union of two $G_\delta$ sets is a $G_\delta$ set. Oh, you also need that the union of two measure zero sets has measure zero, but I'm sure you already have that.